# Vertical alignment of subplot titles with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with multiple subplots, some being data graphs and some images. The image data will typically determine the size of the axes automatically, which is good. However, when I add titles to the different subplots, the titles are a different vertical positions. Here is a (reduced) example:

```py
import pylab as plt

plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('A')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(plt.randn(10, 10))
plt.title('B')

plt.show()
```

See below for the output: [image]

As you can see, the titles (A and B) are at different vertical positions. I am aware that I could manually set the `pad` parameter of the title function, but I was wondering if there is an automatic way to do so as well.

Comment: There is no equivalent of `align_labels` for titles. Are you aiming at calculating the `pad`? Why not use a normal text positionned in figure coordinates instead?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have much experience with Matplotlib, but if you change the line

```
plt.subplot(122)
```

to

```
plt.subplot(222)
```

you should get the result I think you want.

Comment: Actually, the real figure is 2x2 and it's the same problem.